# Standards for data availability for internal employees

Tags: gdpr, data-protection, personal-information, data

Our organization possesses a lot of personal data, and when we provide the data to external partners we are very strict on complying with all the data confidentiality rules, recommendations, etc. The external partners must provide a valid reason to get the personal data. We work in the EU, so the [GDPR](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=celex%3A02016R0679-20160504) is our base document when dealing with personal data. There is the data minimisation principle (Article 5):

> 1. Personal data shall be:
>    <...>
>    (c) adequate, relevant and limited to what is necessary in relation to
>    the purposes for which they are processed (‘data minimisation’);

We currently interpret this principle on the level of the organization, i.e., the whole organization is the data "processor".

But we often debate how to deal with personal data access for **internal employees**. My understanding has always been that data access internally should be regulated according to the same standards as externally. But I am having a hard time proving this to fellow employees.

Does the GDPR's data minimisation principle apply to every employee individually? Is there another data-protection-related document/ article which I could provide or even cite to my colleagues, saying that internal and external information security should comply with the same standards?

Comment: You've made a leap in logic. The organisation, as an *entity*, is the Data Controller or Processor. That does not mean that every employee in that organisation has the right to all the data collected from the data subjects. The janitors have no right to the information, for example.

Comment: An organisation should consider investing in competent legal advice about this, particularly if the prevailing wind is against what should now be common sense.

Answer (score 12):

> 1. Personal data shall be:
>
> (f) processed in a manner that ensures appropriate security of the personal data, including protection against unauthorised or unlawful processing and against accidental loss, destruction or damage, using appropriate technical or organisational measures (‘integrity and confidentiality’).

[Article 5](https://gdpr-info.eu/art-5-gdpr/)

That means it should only be accessible to those employees who “need to know”, only for as long as such need exists, and only for the purposes for which the data was collected.

Consider personal data of an employee - let’s call them Pat. Who needs to know their:

1. Name
2. Email address
3. Physical address
4. Phone number
5. Bank account details
6. Tax number
7. Medical history
8. Rate of pay
9. Spouse’s name and contact details
10. Accumulated leave entitlements
11. Driver’s licence number
12. Educational qualifications

I could go on. The organisation probably needs to know all, or nearly all, of those things about Pat in order to pay them, keep them safe, contact them, contact their next of kin, etc. That is, there is a legitimate reason for collecting and processing the data. However, not everyone in the organisation needs to know all of those things - some people might not need to know anything - if Pat works in Berlin, the branch office in Madrid probably doesn’t even need to know Pat exists.

If people who do not need to know have access, or they lack an audit trail to determine who has accessed it and when, then that would appear to be a failure to implement “appropriate security”.

Comment: You have mentioned audit trail. If many employees had superfluous access to most of the data in the list (not only limited to data of employees of the company, but much wider population), BUT we had an audit trail, it seems, we would have properly implemented "appropriate security". What constitutes a proper audit trail? I assume, just having logs is not enough, we would need to have processes of review, etc.?

Comment: @ZygD An audit trail, a record of who accessed what, is unlikely to be sufficient, even if there is regular review of it and punishment of access without authorisation (you may also find yourself on legally uncertain ground if you try to punish someone for unauthorised access who happened to have permission to access or was not restricted from access). Access to X should be restricted to those who need access to X; access to Y should be restricted to those who need access to Y;  access to Z should be restricted to those who need access to Z. Think of it like a military operation: need to know.

Comment: @ZygD suppose you hold medical information, and an employee inappropriately obtains someone's medical records with the intention of publicizing them or passing them to someone who has no right to the information.  The audit logs aren't going to help you unless you can catch the employee before the improper dissemination of the data and prevent it.  If you wake up and see it in the news, it will be too late.

Comment: @ZygD an audit trail is only useful for forensically responding to a breach. The fundamental protection is that only employees who need to know can access the data in the first place, for example, who needs to know the employee’s bank account? The person who enters it into the payroll system (which ideally would be the person themselves), the bank (preferably in an encrypted way but you have to use the bank’s software which might not do that), and anyone who might need to investigate why a transfer failed. And that’s it. The payroll database should be designed to lock that info up tight.

Answer (score 8):

If you read further-on in the GDPR, article 32 gives you the answer, especially under

> 2. In assessing the appropriate level of security account shall be taken in particular of the risks that are presented by processing, in particular from accidental or unlawful destruction, loss, alteration, unauthorised disclosure of, or access to personal data transmitted, stored or otherwise processed.

and

> 4. The controller and processor shall take steps to ensure that any natural person acting under the authority of the controller or the processor who has access to personal data does not process them except on instructions from the controller, unless he or she is required to do so by Union or Member State law.

So, you must take steps that ensure that your employees do not process data, unless they are instructed to do so.

In addition, depending on the field that your organisation works in and the country, there may be a code of conduct, as referred to in art.40 of the GDPR. These codes may offer additional advice or obligations.

Answer (score 7):

Data minimization means that the organization should not store unnecessary data (that is, "personal data shall be relevant and limited to what is necessary").

You are asking about access to this data by employees.  Employees are agents of their employer, so if an employee stores some data somewhere that is not relevant to the purpose, then the company has done so.  Therefore, as MSalters notes, the company has a right and a duty to instruct its employees accordingly and to enforce those instructions as necessary.

I am writing to note that there is another relevant subparagraphs of paragraph 1, namely 1(f):

> Personal data shall be:
>
> (f) processed in a manner that ensures appropriate security of the personal data, including protection against unauthorised or unlawful processing and against accidental loss, destruction or damage, using appropriate technical or organisational measures (‘integrity and confidentiality’).

Confidentiality implies that employees should have access only to data that they require to perform the tasks that the employer assigns to them.

Comment: Not having a legal background, but very carefully reading the subparagraph f, I find two references to "access only to data that they require": "protection against unauthorised or unlawful processing" and "confidentiality". The obvious way to implement this is to completely restrict access to what is not necessary. Wouldn't you think that there's a kind of "hole" here - I think the points in subparagraph f would legally be fulfilled if the employees had access to all the data, but the employer would have explicitly stated that the full access is needed (even though often unused)?

Comment: @ZygD for the employer, it is ultimately a question of costs and benefits of restricting access.  In a small company, giving everyone access and then hiring people you trust and maintaining that trust because you work closely with the people may be enough.  In addition to the question of who has access, one might also consider whether access is logged.  The employer's "explicit statement" that full access is needed isn't enough.  There needs to be a reasonable justification, not just a bald claim, that a need exists.

Comment: A legally-savvy employer can write a reasonably valid justification. At which point many employees gain fully authorised access to see and process data. Which leads to my point that the subparagraph f condition is satisfied. I mean, just from the legal stand point, just this isolated condition. Of course, the company will risk its reputation in case some employee turns out to have malicious intents. But that's the risk the company takes - a separate topic.

Answer (score 5):

The internal principle is that the employer (as a whole) has to oblige by the GDPR, and is able to do so by virtue of its ability to give specific work instructions to employees. Again, for these work instructions you apply the "limited to what is necessary" principle.

The GDPR is probably a bit more explicit about contracts with third parties, because contracts are usually negotiated between parties. The GDPR reminds you not to negotiate away your responsibilities. Work instructions like these are not subject to negotiation. You simply tell employees what they need to do so that the company doesn't break any laws.

Answer (score 2):

In response to this part of the question (and because the question was originally on `Information Security Stack Exchange`):

> But we often debate how to deal with personal data access for internal employees. My understanding has always been that data access internally should be regulated according to the same standards as externally. But I am having a hard time proving this to fellow employees.

Even if it isn't required by law, from an IT security standpoint if you have a bad actor within your organization you want to limit the amount of damage they can do. This generally means giving everyone minimum access they need to do their job for only as long as they need it. It is called the "principle of least privilege" (https://google.github.io/building-secure-and-reliable-systems/raw/ch05.html).

The bad actor could be

- as innocent as "oh, I know this person, I wonder what their birthday is so I can get them a surprise gift"
- to scary and damaging to users "I could download this spreadsheet of everyone's personal information and sell it"
- or in a worse case "This is a terrible company, I'm going to delete all their customer information and ruin them cause I'm going to get fired anyways"

No matter the case, you really don't want anyone to have access to anything they don't need. It is industry standard and best practice (from a security perspective) to implement the "principle of least privilege".

That being said, implementing security standards and practices can be painful, expensive, and make it harder for everyone to do their jobs which is why you will see push back.